# C# calling function from other class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run "progr.SetMonitorState(MonitorState.OFF)" in "public static void Main()", but I'm getting errors while trying to compile it:

1. "SetMonitorState" doesn't exists in progr namespace...
2. "MonitorState" doesn't exists in current context...

I'm just trying to make program that will shutdown my pc and turn off monitor (I want to check if it will turn off my TV connected with PC via HDMI)

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace progr
{
    public class MonitorSht
    {
        public int SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170;
        public uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public enum MonitorState
        {
            ON = -1,
            OFF = 2,
            STANDBY = 1
        }

        public void SetMonitorState(MonitorState state)
        {
            Form frm = new Form();

            SendMessage(frm.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)SC_MONITORPOWER,(IntPtr)state);

        }
    }

    public class Shut
    {  
       public static void Main()
       {
          progr.SetMonitorState(MonitorState.OFF);

          Console.Write("Jestem jebanym leniem :)\n\n");      
          int t=0;
          for (int i=0;i<7;i++) 
          {       
              Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1} min", i,t);
              t=t+30;
          }
          Console.Write("[7] Anuluj\n");
          Console.Write("\n\nZa ile wyłączyć sprzęcior?");

          int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

          switch (n)
          {
              case 0: n=0; break;
              case 1: n=1800; break;
              case 2: n=3600; break;
              case 3: n=5400; break;
              case 4: n=7200; break;
              case 5: n=9000; break;
              case 6: n=10800; break;
          }

          string sht = "/s /t " + n;
          if (n==7) {sht = "/a";}

          Console.Write(sht);
          var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown",sht);
          psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
          psi.UseShellExecute = false;
          Process.Start(psi);

          Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to make an instance of `MonitorSht` in order to use it. You are trying to access your namespace which doesn't really make sense

Comment: They are in the class `MonitorSht`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `MonitorSht` is not static so you need to create an instance in order to use its methods.

```
public static void Main()
{
   var monitorSht = new MonitorSht();
   monitorSht.SetMonitorState(MonitorSht.MonitorState.OFF);

   Console.Write("Jestem jebanym leniem :)\n\n");   
   /*...*/
}
```

You could also expose your enum by putting it outside of a scope of the class, preferably in a new file.

```
public class MonitorSht
{
 /*...*/
}

public enum MonitorState
 {
     ON = -1,
     OFF = 2,
     STANDBY = 1
 }
```

Then you could just write:

```
var monitorSht = new MonitorSht();
monitorSht.SetMonitorState(MonitorState.OFF);
```

You should read more about how classes work.

Comment: I have started today, I'll read for sure. Now I get error "Monitorstate doesn't exist in current context"

Comment: In order to access your enum you have to write name of your class, then name of your enum and then enum's value, so `MonitorSht.MonitorState.OFF`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to make instance from your MonitorSht like below in Main method:

```
MonitorSht somename = new MonitorSht();
```

and then call your method through the instance like this:
`somename.SetMonitorState(MonitorState.OFF)`

Answer (score 1):

try this as your is question calling a method from another class

```
using [projectName].[classLocation];
```

eg

```
using projectX.Models;
```

Then make an instance of an object
eg

```
SetMonitorState Monitor = new SetMonitorState();
```

then to get the methods inside this class just call Monitor 
eg

```
Monitor.ShutDown();
```